# NullPointerException at org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.daemon.TestRunner.executeTest(TestRunner.java:40)

Tags: java, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-swarm

When an arquillian test tries to deploy a war I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.daemon.TestRunner.executeTest(TestRunner.java:40)
at org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.daemon.server.Server.executeTest(Server.java:250)
at org.wildfly.swarm.arquillian.daemon.server.Server$StringCommandHandler.channelRead0(Server.java:361)
...
```

Actually `deploymentUnit` is `null` at line:40 what means `TestRunner` constructor was invoked with parameter `deploymentUnit` = `null`

When I launch the application built without tests and re-packaged as fat-jar, it starts without problems

I am using wildfly-swarm 2018.3.0

Any ideas how could this happen?

Comment: I recall seing something similar in the past, but can't remember the cause and how I fixed it. Do you have a small reproducing project somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to publish the project and I am not able to reproduce this behavior on some other... I know it is really hard if possible to analyse it this way, I was only wondering if someone already faced same or similar issue...

Comment: How are you creating the deployment? Do you return an initialized, valid archive (in method decorated with @Deployment)?

Comment: I am not creating archive, everything is created automatically based on project-defaults.yml. There is no MainClass nor main-method to create my deployment and I used @DefaultDeployment annotation